# Where do I declare my external service in my app.module.ts file?

Tags: angular, service, module

I'm using Angular 7 and trying to have my app use an external service I've created.  I created the service at

```
src/shared/currency.service.ts
```

and have this in my src/app/app.module.ts file ...

```
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CurrencyService,
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CurrencyService,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CurrencyService
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts looks like

```
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  currencies: any;
  title = 'app';
  apiStatus: string;
  constructor(private _currencySrv: CurrencyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

}
```

But when I visit my page, I get the JS error

```
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CurrencyService' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
    at eval (compiler.js:15240)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15215)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34268)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5578)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

What else do I need to do to right the ship?

Comment: either provide it in `providers` array or add `providedIn:'root'` inside `@Injectable`: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. Remove from imports, exports and declarations

Comment: Also remove it from `imports`; you can only import modules.

Comment: also if you were to use Angular CLI to create the service, this would be automatically done for you :)

Comment: @Zircon, I removed it from imports and added CurrencyService to providers, and now get the error, "Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CurrencyService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation"

Comment: You need to remove it from `declarations` as well. You only need `CurrencyService` in one place and that is in `providers` if you are not using `providedIn: 'root'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services need to either be added to the `providers` array:

```js
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [CurrencyService], // <-- in here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

...or, at the beginning of your service, you add the `Injectable` decorator and specify the `providedIn` property:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CurrencyService {}
```